# Not able to update entity with multipart/formdata - NgRx Data

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-data

I am trying to update one of my entity which has file upload functionality as well. I can send(add) FormData using add method, but can't update. NgRx gives below error:

> Error: Primary key may not be null/undefined.

Is this even possible? Or am I doing something wrong. Please have a look at below code:

```js
const ad = {
  id: form.id,
  accountId: this.accountId
}

const data = new FormData();
data.append('ad', JSON.stringify(ad));

// photos is an array of uploaded files
if(this.photos.length) {
  this.photos.forEach(photo => {
    data.append('offure_ad', photo, photo['name']);
  });
}

// NgRx Data update mothod
this.adService.update(data);
```

Please direct me to right direction. Thank you

Comment: are you sending primary key in the request?

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code

```js
const ad = {
  id: form.id,
  accountId: this.accountId
}

const data = new FormData();
data.append('ad', JSON.stringify(ad));

// photos is an array of uploaded files
if(this.photos.length) {
  this.photos.forEach(photo => {
    data.append('offure_ad', photo, photo['name']);
  });
}

// send ad like below
this.adService.update(data,ad);
```

Comment: Second parameter of update method accepts only EntityActionOptions type. We can not pass anything there.

Comment: Well, It's NgRx Data's built in method. Do you have a good context over NgRx Data library? @Raj

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a DataService class and use a custom update function like this.

```
@Injectable()
export class PromotionDataService extends DefaultDataService<Promotion> {

  httpClient: HttpClient;

  constructor(httpClient: HttpClient, httpUrlGenerator: HttpUrlGenerator) {
    super('Promotion', httpClient, httpUrlGenerator);
    this.httpClient = httpClient;
  }

  updatePromotion(promotionId: string, formData: FormData): Observable<Promotion> {

    formData.append('_method', 'PUT');

    return this.httpClient.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/v1/manager/promotion/` + promotionId, formData)
      .pipe(map((response: Promotion) => {
        return response;
      }));
  }
}
```

I am using post request, because put request is not working with multipart/form-data. Then register the data service as follow.

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    PromotionDataService
  ]
})
export class EntityStoreModule {
  constructor(
    entityDataService: EntityDataService,
    promotionDataService: PromotionDataService,
  ) {
    entityDataService.registerService('Promotion', promotionDataService);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PromotionComponent,
  ],
  exports: [

  ],
  imports: [
    EntityStoreModule
  ],
})
export class PromotionModule {}
```

in your component first inject the data service in the constructor, then you can use the custom update function like this

```
  onSubmit() {

    if (this.promotionForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    const newPromotion: Promotion = this.promotionForm.value;

    const fileControl = this.f.banner;

    let files: File[];
    let file: File = null;

    if(fileControl.value){
      files = fileControl.value._files
    }

    if(files && files.length > 0) {
      file = files[0];
    }

    const formData = new FormData();

    if(file != null){
      formData.append('banner', file, file.name);
    }

    formData.append('data', JSON.stringify(newPromotion));

    this.service.updatePromotion(promotion.id, formData)

  }
```